# Unable to provide a binding for a Keybinding

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5

I have a UserControl that contains a Dev Express grid control and I am trying to wire up a command to handle when the user presses the delete key while a row is selected.

My first iteration was:

```
<dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItemCommand}"/>
</dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
```

When inspecting the result at runtime with Snoop I was seeing this error for the binding:
`System.Windows.Data Error:2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=39502614); target property is'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

After doing some research I found several posts that said they were able to achieve this by adding a relative source so I changed my binding to this:

```
<dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=views:MyUserControl}}"/>
</dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
```

Now at runtime I was seeing this error:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='MyProject.Views.MyUserControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteItemCommand; DataItem=null; target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=35267081); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

In the research I did I noticed that this functionality was added in .NET 4.0 but I am using .NET 4.5 so that shouldn't be the problem.

I also noticed that all of the examples were specifying the `InputBindings` at the window level so while within my app It isn't feasible to do the same I did try to move the bindings up to the user control level but received the same results.

Also not sure if it matters but my user control inherits a custom base class as well and because of this I cannot try using a named element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to use proxy to the DataContext that contains the DeleteItemCommand command definition and use that proxy to access the command you need. I think that the reason you can't access the command and have a BindingExpression error is the fact the you are not in the same logical tree with your DataGrid object. Here several point that in my opinion can help you with your problem.

**Proxy class:**

```
public class FreezableProxyClass : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new FreezableProxyClass();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProxiedDataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ProxiedDataContext", typeof (object), typeof (FreezableProxyClass), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object ProxiedDataContext
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(ProxiedDataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProxiedDataContextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Proxy class xaml declaration (This is the name of control that has the DataContext you need):**

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:FreezableProxyClass x:Key="ProxyElement" ProxiedDataContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

**Proxy Class Usage**

```
 <dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, 
                Path=ProxiedDataContext.DeleteItemCommand}"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.InputBindings>
```

**Update**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dataGridSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:DataGridSoHelpAttempt"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Window.DataContext>
    <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:FreezableProxyClass x:Key="ProxyElement" ProxiedDataContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid></Window>
```

As you can see *This* is the name of the window containing the grid. Thus I don't need to define a relative binding of FreezableProxyClass, it access the main window DataContext directly.
I'll be happy to help if you will have problems with the code.

Regards.

Comment: This doesn't work, on opening the form the {x:Reference This} binding is throwing an error: `Unresolved reference 'This'`

Comment: I was able to get your code working by changing the proxy binding to `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MyUserControl}}`

Comment: @Phaeze this is th name of the main window or control in which data context are you interested. please see the update.

Comment: Ahh ok, unfortunately due to my object structure I am unable to provide the name attribute on my user control (it has a custom base class) so I need to use the relative binding.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds unlikely, but what worked for me was to reference the inputBinding collection as a **static resource**, from within a style. I suspect the fact the imporant part was that it is a static resource, not necessarily that I did so from a style.

My Style was bound to a TreeViewItem, not a grid:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="behaviors:InputBinder.InputBindings" Value="{StaticResource itemBindings}"/>
</Style>
```

My itemBindings resource looked similar to yours:

```
    <InputBindingCollection x:Key="itemBindings" x:Shared="False">
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding F2Command}" Key="F2"/>
    </InputBindingCollection>
```

When I used a dynamic resource, or when I assigned the binding collection directly to the control, I got the error message you mentioned.

The InputBindings attached property I used looks as follows:

```
public static class InputBinder
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputBindingsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached
    (
        "InputBindings",
        typeof(InputBindingCollection),
        typeof(InputBinder),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new InputBindingCollection(), (sender, e) =>
        {

            var element = (UIElement)sender;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.InputBindings.Clear();
                element.InputBindings.AddRange((InputBindingCollection)e.NewValue);
            }
        })
    );

    public static InputBindingCollection GetInputBindings(UIElement element)
    {
        return (InputBindingCollection)element.GetValue(InputBindingsProperty);
    }

    public static void SetInputBindings(UIElement element, InputBindingCollection inputBindings)
    {
        element.SetValue(InputBindingsProperty, inputBindings);
    }
}
```